# Assign single object to list of object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a model with a simple `Guid`:

```
public class GuidIdTableType
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I have a model where I create a list of model used before:

```
public class SelectModel
        {
          ....
    public List<GuidIdTableType> MyGuidTableTypeList { get; set; } = new List<GuidIdTableType>();

        }
```

Now I get a list of objects in my code like:

```
  var currentModel = _myRepository.Get(model);
```

And I want to fill my list of guids with an object inside that list, So I try:

```
 var model = new SelectModel();
                foreach(var i in currentModel.Result)
                {
                    var rModel = new SelectModel();

                    rModel.MyGuidTableTypeList = i.Assignee;

                    model.MyGuidTableTypeList.Add(rModel);
                }
```

But it throws an error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

What am I doing wrong?. Regards

Comment: Its a bit difficult to read since i do not have all the code, but i see the same property (well name) being called twice. rModel.UserIdtableType = I.Assignee and then you add to a list on a property of the same name on a different instance. Is that code correct? Could you add more into the examples

Comment: Sorry, I already fixed that. @DaveyvanTilburg

Comment: why you use ``rModel`` in loop, must be ``GuidIdTableType`` no? i think in loop you need just this``model.MyGuidTableTypeList.Add(new GuidIdTableType{Id=i.Assignee})``

Comment: Where are you adding to your list MyGuidTableTypeList?  Looks like code is failing for another reason.

Comment: That's exactly that I want @Sajid , Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome! you can do it better by Linq without foreach.

Comment: Can you give me an example of linq? @Sajid

Comment: ``var model = new SelectModel
            {
                MyGuidTableTypeList = currentModel.Result.Select(i => new GuidIdTableType { Id = i.Assignee }).ToList()
            };``

Comment: Ohhh, and what about if I want to create multiple lists, I mean in this example we only have one, but suppose we need more we need to repeat that code I mean `model1=... , model2=... model3=...`,  it is still the best option to use linq instead a foreach? @Sajid

Comment: yeah, you manage the different cases. but here you have one ``currentModel`` and one ``model``, so you can use my last proposition or @RohitGarg proposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are adding 'rModel' to GuidIdTableType property of 'model'.  rModel and model are of same type i.e. SelectModel. It doesn't make sense. You may want to try something like below:

```
var model = new SelectModel();
                foreach(var i in currentModel.Result)
                { 

                    model.MyGuidTableTypeList.Add(new GuidIdTableType{id = i.Assignee}); // considering i.Assignee is Guid
                }
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried to comment that as well but couldn't wrap my head around it. But you saved the day! :)